# Error de array: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de devolver los valores de un array de nombres después de ser ingresados por consola, pero me sale este error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2error
```

No consigo dar con la solución, agradezco de antemano cualquier explicación que puedan darme.

El código es este:

```java
package retoArrayNombres;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class reto {

    private static Scanner captura;
    static int tamanioArray = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        capturatamanio(); 
        capturaNombres();
    }

    public static int capturatamanio() {

        System.out.print("Por favor ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: ");

        try {
            captura = new Scanner(System.in);
            tamanioArray = captura.nextInt();

            if (tamanioArray > 0) {
                System.out.print("Tamaño capturado\n");
            }else {
                System.out.print("Por favor ingrese un número diferente de 'cero'\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Por favor ingrese un número, las letras no determinan el tamaño\n");
        }

            return tamanioArray; 
    }

    public static String capturaNombres() {
        int i ;
        captura = new Scanner(System.in);
        String [] nombres = new String[tamanioArray];
        for (i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Por favor ingrese el nombre de la posición " + i + " " );
            nombres[i] = captura.nextLine(); 
        }
        return nombres[i].toString();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando hace `return nombres[i].toString();`, el valor de `i` es igual a `tamanioArray + 1` (es mayor que el length maximo de nombres). Es porque se genera el error.

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría preguntar el objetivo de guardarlos que planeas hacer con ellos después.
Tu problema es que quieres retornar un valor string[] <- lo cual significa que es un array a una función que guarda un valor string singular, para corregirlo haría falta que tu código luzca de la siguiente manera.

```
public static String [] capturaNombres() {
    int i ;
    captura = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] nombres = new String[tamanioArray];
    for (i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Por favor ingrese el nombre de la posición " + i + " " );
        nombres[i] = captura.nextLine(); 
    }
    return nombres; 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que quiero es mostrarle al usuario los valores que ingresó, logré qué los mostrara de otra manera, pero voy a intentarlo de la manera que me recomiendas, quizá se acerque más a lo que quiero, muchas gracias por responder

Comment: Por favor mantenme informado para ayudarte lo mas que pueda, y cualquier duda aqui estoy